# How to compare result of two subqueries in where clause SQLKata

Tags: c#, subquery, where-clause, sqlkata

I try to compare results of two subqueries in where clause in SQLKata.

In SQL it should be like this:

```
WHERE (SELECT count(id) FROM main.someTable) = (SELECT count(id) FROM main.anotherTable)
```

In SQLKata I can compare result of subquery with scalar value:

```
var mainSubquery = new Query("main.someTable")
            .SelectRaw("count(id)");

var anotherSubquery = new Query("main.anotherTable")
            .SelectRaw("count(id)");

query
    .WhereSub(mainSubquery, "=", 0)
```

But I can't compare results of two subqueries this way:

```
query
    .WhereSub(mainSubquery, "=", anotherSubquery),
```

How can I fix it? Maybe I should execute both of the subqueries and only then compare their results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No overload accepts queries on both the left and right sides together.

But you can always compile the queries and use the `WhereRaw`. One gotcha is to be aware of the bindings orders.

Take a look on this example:

```
using SqlKata;
using SqlKata.Compilers;

var sub1 = new Query("A").SelectRaw("count(1)");
var sub2 = new Query("B").SelectRaw("count(1)");

var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
var c1 = compiler.Compile(sub1);
var c2 = compiler.Compile(sub2);
var bindings = c1.Bindings;
bindings.AddRange(c2.Bindings); // order (c1, c2) is important here

var query = new Query("Table").WhereRaw($"({c1.Sql}) = ({c2.Sql})", bindings);

var result = compiler.Compile(query);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

This will output the following

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE (SELECT count(1) FROM [A]) = (SELECT count(1) FROM [B])
```

Comment: and what can you say about performance? What is better - `WhereSub` or `WhereRaw` ?

Comment: Same thing, this is how Sqlkata is internally implemented